# Accessing value of instance variables scala

Tags: scala

I'm really new to Scala so this might seem obvious to most of you but here is my problem. I created a simple class to create tickets for a burger truck:

```
class Tickets() {  
  var burgerPrice = 2.00
  var frenchFriesPrice = 1.00
  var milkshakePrice = 3.00
  var taxes = 0.08

  def calculatePrices(burgersNum: Int, frenchFriesNum: Int, milkshakesNum: Int) = {

    val price = (burgersNum*burgerPrice + frenchFriesNum*frenchFriesPrice + milkshakesNum*milkshakePrice) * (1+taxes)

    price 
    }
  }
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to create now a function inside an object to print subtotals and the total price of every receipt. To do such thing, I have tried:

```
 object receipt{
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val importe = new Tickets()

     val burgersNum = readLine("Welcome to my shop. How many burgers do you want? ").toInt
     val frenchFriesNum = readLine("How many French fries? ").toInt
     val milkshakesNum = readLine("Any milkshakes? ").toInt

     println("Burgers: " + burgersNum + "Price: " + Tickets.burgerPrice)
    }
  }
```

But trying to access the variable in Tickets to obtain the price doesn't seem to work. Is there an easy way that I'm missing?

Comment: You have not passed dynamic arguments that you are reading from std input to your ticket object, is not that what you want?? Also, what is your expected result??

Comment: If you're starting scala without much knowledge of OOP, you'd be better off trying to learn it directly as a functional programming language, to avoid mutability pit falls. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info for how and why you should use scala.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to invoke the method of your object to get the result, thats what you are missing, see `importe.calculatePrices(3, 4, 5)` in following example

```
    object receipt {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val importe = new Tickets()

        val burgersNum = readLine("Welcome to my shop. How many burgers do you want? ").toInt
        val frenchFriesNum = readLine("How many French fries? ").toInt
        val milkshakesNum = readLine("Any milkshakes? ").toInt

        println("Burgers: " + burgersNum + "Price: " + importe.calculatePrices(burgersNum, frenchFriesNum, milkshakesNum))
      }
    }
```

read about OOP in java or scala.

https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/object_oriented_programming

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/oops-concepts/